Nginx auth_request alternative for multiple cookies - no Lua
I am trying to authenticate file access based on cookies.
I started off with something like this:
location /private/ {
    auth_request     /auth;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    auth_request_set $saved_set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $saved_set_cookie;

    try_files $uri @pull_file;
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:443/Access/Get;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;
}

Real quick about the try_files, it is part of the origin-pull CDN config. If $uri is not found, @pull_file will acquire it, place it on the path and return the file. This all works as expected.
So in the example above, the /auth location proxy will set multiple cookies. So as you can see I am using $upstream_http_set_cookie to access these cookies and push them back with the requested file to the client.
This only works for the first cookie. The second cookie is ignored. I have found a workaround with $upstream_cookie_[name] where I can explicitly access my cookies by name, but the problem here is that all the cookie attributes are stripped (such as expiration time, path, strict, SameSite etc).
I also found that the $upstream_http_set_cookie being able to access only the first cookie was reported as an issue here and it says it was fixed with Nginx version 1.16.x. I am running Nginx 1.18.0 and I have this issue. Maybe I am not understanding this whole issue/resolution thing properly. If that is so, please shed some light.
I have talked to ChatGPT on this matter and it came up with something like this:
location /private/ {
    # Forward the request to the auth backend first
    proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:443/Access/Get;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;

    # Intercept errors and handle them
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 401 = @unauthorized;

    # Step 3: If authentication is successful, try to serve the file directly or fallback to @pull_file
    error_page 200 = @try_files;
}

location @try_files {
    internal;
    try_files $uri @pull_file;
}

The issue here was the line error_page 200 = @try_files; because code 200 is not considered as an error code and Nginx throws an exception. At this point ChatGPT got stuck in a loop of answers so I tried replacing this line with try_files $uri @pull_file;. So now I got my cookies set up properly in the response, but that was because the proxy response was going back to the client instead of trying files.
So in the last couple of days of trying to understand what was going on and trying to find a solution, I found that the lua-nginx-module would solve this. The thing is, and nothing against Lua, is that I am close to releasing my project to production and at this stage I have already created a small ecosystem with nginx and from what I see installing lua-nginx-module is not as easy as apt-get install... and I would like to avoid any bigger changes in the infrastructure at this point unless I really have to.
So the bottom line is that I am trying to find a way around auth_request, $upstream_http_set_cookie and Lua solution (due to the lack of knowledge, time to learn, and complexity of the rest of my infrastructure).
The expected turn of events for this request are in order:

authenticate the request (done)
pass new cookies back from authentication request if they were set with the response (the issue)
try the file if it exists on the path (done)
if the file doesn't exist acquire it from an api, store on path for next use and return the file (done)

The things I am definitely not willing to change:

authentication mechanism using php sessions (no JWT)
origin-pull CDN mechanism

Any suggestions are appreciated :)
Update 24-Jul-24
Mapping $upstream_http_set_cookie
I tried the suggestion from @djboris with the following configuration:
map $saved_set_cookie $cookie1_value {
    "~*(?<u>^cookie1=[^;]+)" "$u; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    default "dummy=nothing"; # if this cookie was not set let's not overwrite the old one
}
map $saved_set_cookie $cookie2_value {
    "~*(?<u>^cookie2=[^;]+)" "$u; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    default "dummy=nothing"; # if this cookie was not set let's not overwrite the old one
}

server {
    ...
    location /private/ {
        auth_request     /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        
        auth_request_set $saved_set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie; # tried with $sent_http_set_cookie as well, same result
        # Re-set cookies
        add_header Set-Cookie "$cookie1_value";
        add_header Set-Cookie "$cookie2_value";

        try_files $uri @pull_file;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:443/Access/Get;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;
    }
}

Unfortunately this only worked for the cookie which was set first by my application. I thought this might be related to my version of nginx (1.18.0), but I bumped the version to 1.24.0 and had the same outcome.
From what I read on most discussions, handling Set-Cookie headers is a special case and headers like this cannot be folded as comma-separated since the expire attribute uses comma within its value.
More on this here and here.
Diving deeper into Nginx Lua module
Out of curiosity, I invested a bit more time in nginx-lua-module solution. From what I figured is that this module had been removed from nginx builds due to numerous compatibility issue. The instructions on the official repository discourages building the module with nginx by yourself and suggest switching to OpenResty.
So again I gave up on that solution because of my project constraints.
A patch as a solution
Finally, I was desperate enough to try this:
map $cookie1_value $cookie1_cookie {
    "~(?<u>.+)" "cookie1=$u; path=/; domain=mydomain.local; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict";
    default "dummy=nothing";
}
map $cookie2_value $cookie2_cookie {
    "~(?<u>.+)" "cookie2=$u; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=mydomain.local; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict";
    default "dummy=nothing";
}

server {
    ...
    location /private/ {
        auth_request     /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        
        auth_request_set $cookie1_value $upstream_cookie_cookie1;
        auth_request_set $cookie2_value $upstream_cookie_cookie2;
        add_header Set-Cookie $cookie1_cookie;
        add_header Set-Cookie $cookie2_cookie;

        try_files $uri @pull_file;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:443/Access/Get;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;
    }
}

Since I am using only two cookies in my application (session cookie and autologin cookie), this solution is acceptable for me, even though I don't like this patch.
This stores values in variables with auth_request_set $[name]_value $upstream_cookie_[name];. Those values are then mapped with the map directive using a regular expression (maybe not the best possible way). There is a default value for both cookies so not to override existing cookies if the new ones hadn't been set. The newly formed cookies are finally set with add_header Set-Cookie $[name]_cookie;.
Conclusion

It is a solution for multiple cookies if you know the names and can replicate settings for cookies.
It is a bad solution because the cookie settings are hardcoded in nginx configuration instead of only being set at the place they originated from (which is the applicaiton)
It is a bad solution because configuration needs to be extended for each new cookie
Works for me but still looking for a better solution :)


I've had similar requirement while working on streaming service for a client. Would this be an option for you to consider? https://www.f5.com/company/blog/nginx/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus. This is random google search link. Other than that you shoul provide more details in a form of a small docker example setup and curl requests so that we can easily test your setup instead of thinking inside our heads about it.

Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is not the direction I am willing to go. The links in my app are doing authentication as well as authorization for each resource against user privileges. These are prone to changes individually for each user. So as I stated in the post, I am not willing to change the authentication mechanism.

Given your constraints and the issues you've encountered with handling multiple cookies and their attributes in Nginx, a potential workaround involves using Nginx's map directive to explicitly capture and re-set the cookies from the upstream response. This approach allows you to work around the limitation of $upstream_http_set_cookie only capturing the first Set-Cookie header and the loss of cookie attributes when using $upstream_cookie_[name].
The idea is to use the map directive to extract cookies from the Set-Cookie headers and then use additional add_header directives to set these cookies in the client response. This method requires you to know the names of the cookies you want to capture and re-set.  Here's a step-by-step plan:

Use the map directive to capture cookies from the upstream response. You'll need to add these directives to the http block of your Nginx configuration. For each cookie you expect to receive, create a separate map block.

Re-set the cookies in the client response using add_header Set-Cookie. You'll use the variables set by the map directive here.

Ensure that multiple Set-Cookie headers can be added by using add_header multiple times as needed for each cookie.


Here's an example configuration snippet:
http {
    map $upstream_http_set_cookie $cookie_1_value {
        ~*^cookie1=([^;]+) $1;
    }
    map $upstream_http_set_cookie $cookie_2_value {
        ~*^cookie2=([^;]+) $1;
    }
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location /private/ {
            auth_request     /auth;
            auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            auth_request_set $saved_set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
            
            # Re-set cookies
            add_header Set-Cookie "cookie1=$cookie_1_value; Path=/; HttpOnly";
            add_header Set-Cookie "cookie2=$cookie_2_value; Path=/; HttpOnly";
            ...
            try_files $uri @pull_file;
        }

        location = /auth {
            internal;
            proxy_pass              https://127.0.0.1:443/Access/Get;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header        X-Original-Uri $request_uri;
        }
        ...
    }
}

Note: This example assumes you have cookies named cookie1 and cookie2. You'll need to adjust the regex patterns and variable names according to the actual cookies you're dealing with. Also, this approach might not capture all cookie attributes if they're not consistently set by the upstream server. You may need to manually add these attributes (such as Expires, Max-Age, Domain, Secure, SameSite) in the add_header Set-Cookie directives.
This workaround is not as elegant as handling cookies directly in the application logic or using a more flexible system like Lua, but it should allow you to address the immediate issue without introducing significant changes to your infrastructure.

Thanks very much for a detailed explanation. I assume 'map $upstream_http_set_cookie ...' should be 'map $saved_set_cookie ...' and '~^cookie1=([^;]+) $1;' should be '~^cookie1=(?[^;]+) $g;'.
However, when I send both cookies I still get value of only the first one. If I switch their assignment order I can see the other one shows. Also I have added a default value within map blocks to be sure they are executed properly, and I always get a default value for the one which was assigned last.

My guess is this probably wasn't fixed by nginx for ver. 1.18.0 that I am using, since even though the nginx ticket says this issue was fixed with 1.16.0 some people have complained it wasn't fixed in later versions. So that's why I was looking for a way to perhaps avoid using $upstream_http_set_cookie.

However, of all the map examples I have seen in other answers on SO, this one is best one yet. You might want to update your answer with those tweaks so others might benefit from it as well :)
